# Como reproduzir um ficheiro .mp3 em PHP

Tags: php

Estou aprendendo PHP e preciso da ajuda de vocês. Vi num *post* aqui que é possível tocar um ficheiro `.mp3` em PHP.

Fiz um teste assim:

```
<?php
echo "Teste";
echo "<embed src='11.mp3' width='1' height='1'>";
?>
```

O arquivo `11.mp3` está na mesma pasta do FTP que o `teste.php`.
Mas não está tocando nada. Alguém saberia me dizer porquê?

Answer (score 7):

Na verdade você não está "tocando um .mp3 em php", acredito que para alcançar EXATAMENTE isso o próprio player deveria ser construído em PHP, *nem sei se existe isso.*

Mas, eu entendi o que quis dizer.

O seu código apenas "exibe" um *texto* para o usuário, usando o `echo`. Esse "texto" é um HTML.

Uma solução seria usar o `audio` do HTML ao invés do `embed` como:

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay>
   <source src="11.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Quer uma demostração?!

```html
 <audio id="audio" autoplay controls>
    <source src="https://cdns-preview-8.dzcdn.net/stream/821246fb5d7e2ff6975f65ef7460a708-0.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

A função `audio` tem vários atributos diferentes, incluindo nesse exemplo o `controls` (para exibir os controles, de pausa e tal) e o `autoplay` (para iniciar automaticamente).  [Você pode todos os atributos aqui. ;)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Attributes)

> A prévia da musica, usado no exemplo, foi extraído da [API do Deezer](https://developers.deezer.com/api),  [exatamente aqui](https://api.deezer.com/album/11885698).

**Você NÃO PRECISA de PHP para isso.**

Se quiser mesmo usar o PHP para exibir, poderá usar:

```
echo '<audio id="audio" autoplay>
   <source src="11.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>';
```

Existem outras alternativas, mas não foge disso.

Além disso veja no Console (F12 no Google Chrome) e entre em "Network" e veja se ele está obtendo o arquivo *11.mp3*. Caso esteja como 404, ou qualquer valor diferente de 200, ele pode não estar conseguindo achar o arquivo *11.mp3*.